# Create a notification with different UI elements for a Music Player in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, android-notifications

I'm trying to create a simple music player in Xamarin.Android. In my app I'm creating a started service for background streaming, and I want to create a notification for the user to be abel to interact with the service. Something like this: [image]

I read about notification in Xamarin.Android [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/), but they say nothing about adding buttons and other ui elements. So my question is how do I design a notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look Android documentation about custom notification layouts: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification

> 1. Create an XML layout for the notification in a separate file. You can use any file name you wish, but you must use the extension .xml
> 2. In your app, use RemoteViews methods to define your notification's icons and text. Put this RemoteViews object into your NotificationCompat.Builder by calling setContent(). Avoid setting a background Drawable on your RemoteViews object, because your text color may become unreadable.

Comment: Is this method going to work for Xamarin.Android too?

Comment: Yes, all from Android SDK is available in Xamarin.Android. So if you have some problem feel free to search solution in Java and just translate it to C#.

Comment: I'll try this solution, and I'll let you know if it works or not. I'll do this later though when I'll be able to access my PC.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you